# What does the \ mean in php?

Tags: php, syntax

I have seen \ in links before in php but what does it mean.  For example:

```
echo "<a href=\'/admin/index.php\'>Admin</a>";
```

Comment: It's typically used as an escape sequence.

Comment: in that example its a literal slash. very unlikely to be areal world example

Comment: there is no need for forward slashes with single quotes if you use single quotes inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being used to escape the string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Answer (score -1):

It makes the character after it give a specific output. 
In your case it will output `'` and not use `'` to close the string.

Its called escaping and is used alot. Especially in Regex.

`echo '<a href=\'/admin/index.php\'>Admin</a>';` 
Outputs `<a href='/admin/index.php'>`

The `\` is there just to "escape" the `'`s.

Note:
`echo "<a href=\'/admin/index.php\'>Admin</a>"; // note the encapsulating quotes`
Outputs  `<a href=\'/admin/index.php\'>Admin</a>`

Comment: no in the OP's example the output is `<a href=\'/admin/index.php\'>Admin</a>`

Comment: You are right. echo '<a href=\'/admin/index.php\'>Admin</a>'; returns <a href='/admin/index.php'>